# How to generate Moving Average model

Tags: matlab, moving-average, autoregressive-models

In order to generate Autoregressive model, we have the aryule() command and we can also use filters[Estimating AR model](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/aryule.html). But how do I generate MA model? For instance, can somebody please show how to generate MA(20) model? I could not find any appropriate technique to do so. The noise is generated from a nonlinear map

```
epsilon(1) = 0.01;

for i =1 : N 
        epsilon(i+1) = 4*epsilon(i)*(1-epsilon(i));
    end
```

So, the MA model will regress over `epsilon` terms.

**Q1:** Shall be extremely helpful if the code and functional form of an MA model is shown preferably MA(20) using the above noise model.

**Q2:** This is how I generated an AR(20) using random noise but don't know how to use the above equation as the noise instead of using rand for both MA and AR

```
 %Generate sine wave = A*sin(2*pi*f*t + phi)
t = linspace(0,1,1000);
A = 5;
f = 2;
phi = pi/8;
sinewave = A*sin(2*pi*f*t + phi);
noisy_sine=sinewave+0.5*randn(size(t));
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(t, sinewave)
hold on;
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(t,noisy_sine);

%Generate AR model(20)
order =20;
ARCoeff = aryule(noisy_sine,order);
```

Comment: Does [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arma-model.html) help? Matlab has an autoregressive moving average model in the econometrics toolbox

Comment: in moving average filters the coefficients are just the 1/m, in ur case all coeff would be 1/20 for avg filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same problem.  The following links can help :

https://www.mathworks.com/examples/econometrics/mw/econ-ex18477389-simulate-an-ma-process

---

Simulate an MA Process

This example shows how to simulate sample paths from a stationary MA(12) process without specifying presample observations.

Contents

1. Specify a model.
2. Generate sample paths.
3. Plot the simulation variance.

*Step 1. Specify a model.*

Specify the MA(12) model

[image: {y_t} = 0.5 + {\varepsilon _t} + 0.8{\varepsilon _{t - 1}} + 0.2{\varepsilon _{t - 12}}]

where the innovation distribution is Gaussian with variance 0.2.

```
model = arima('Constant',0.5,'MA',{0.8,0.2},...
              'MALags',[1,12],'Variance',0.2);
```

*Step 2. Generate sample paths.*
Generate 200 sample paths, each with 60 observations.

```
rng('default')
Y = simulate(model,60,'NumPaths',200);
```

*Step 3. Plot the simulation variance.*

```
figure
plot(Y,'Color',[.85,.85,.85])
hold on
h = plot(mean(Y,2),'k','LineWidth',2)
legend(h,'Simulation Mean','Location','NorthWest')
title('MA(12) Process')
hold off
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with one line of code using `filter`.

Let us talk about AR and MA in the Laplace domain. Say that your have a transfer function H = B/A, where B and A are polynomials. B have the coefficients of your MA and A will have your AR coefficients. In equations:

[image]

Thus, given your input signal `x`, you can use Matlab's `y=filter(B,A,x)` to generate your AR, MA and ARMA processes. The documentation about `filter` is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/filtering-data.html).  For your specific case of a pure MA model, just make B=1 and your A as a vector with 20 elements.

You probably already know that, but just in case and to help future readers [here](http://cnx.org/contents/31c2d232-06c2-4aaa-a6cf-499378420b09@7) is a link with a review on how to transform your difference equations to Laplace domain. TL;DR: [image]

Comment: My problem is the use of filter. I am not familiar with Transfer function concept, but you mentioned that numerator $B's$ are the MA coefficients so the B should be the 20 elements and not A's?? Next, let's say the model has an intercept of 0.5, can you please show with the code how I can create an MA model with 0.5 intercept (how to mention the intercept in the filter() and using the input defined in my question please? Thank you for the filter link, that really cleared the doubts about how to use filter.

Comment: In "y = filter(b,a,X) filters the data in vector X with the filter described by numerator coefficient vector b and denominator coefficient vector a. If a(1) is not equal to 1, filter normalizes the filter coefficients by a(1). If a(1) equals 0, filter returns an error." (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) this is the problem area as I don't understand how to specify the a,b (filter coefficients) when there is an intercept of say 0.5 or intercept of 1.Could you please show an example of MA with filter and  a non-zero intercept using the input that I mentioned in the Question?